# How can this indefinite integral be solved without partial fractions?

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

At first I had no doubt that I will have to use partial fractions on this integral:
\begin{equation}
\int \frac{3x^2+4}{x^5+x^3}dx
\end{equation} 
I split it into two integrals and one of them give me back this equation:
\begin{equation}
\ A(x^2+1)+Bx(x^2+1)+Cx^2(x^2+1)+Dx^4+Ex^3 =1
\end{equation} 
Then if I check what happens if $x = 0$ I find out that $A = 1$ after that I checked what happens then $ x =1 \ \ x=-1 \ \ x=2 $ my results there :
\begin{equation}
\ 2B+E=0 \\
\ 2C+D=-1 \\
\ E+2D=2
\end{equation} 
I am realizing that I can joggle variables in any fashion I like I will not be get their values.
So using partial fractions is not effective for this particular case. What other way could you suggest of handling this equation?

P.S. I may have made a calculation mistake. In that case I am sorry for wasting your time but I would appreciate if you could point out my mistake.

**EDIT:** I wrote 'I split it into two integrals' it seams it needs to be shown:
\begin{equation}
3\int \frac{dx}{x^2+1}dx +4 \int \frac{dx}{x^5+x^3}dx = \\
\ \arctan x +4(\int \frac{A}{x^3}dx+\int \frac{B}{x^2}dx+\int \frac{C}{x}dx+\int \frac{Dx+E}{x^2+1}dx)
\end{equation}

Comment: Why do you have $=1$ in the equation and not $=3x^2+4$?

Comment: Once again: "solved" is the wrong word.  One _solves_ problems; one _solves_ equations.  One _evaluates_ expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it can be evaluated easily without partial fractions (see Mike's answer, though). After your edit, I see you set things up correctly with the integral you're using partial fractions on. But you only have three equations (which I haven't checked).  You have four unknowns. Find another equation.

As for the first integral, though, it should be $3\int {dx\over x^3+x}$...

Let's try a decomposition at the start without splitting the integral up first (it would be just as easy):
$$
{3x^2+4\over x^3(x^2+1)}= {A\over x}+{B\over x^2}+{C\over x^3}+{Dx+E\over x^2+1}
$$
Which gives
$$
3x^2+4=Ax^2(x^2+1)+Bx(x^2+1)+C(x^2+1)+(Dx+E)x^3.
$$
Let's figure out what we can be giving $x$ particular values:
Setting $x=0$ gives $C=4$. 
No more nice values.  But we can write now

$$
3x^2+4=Ax^2(x^2+1)+Bx(x^2+1)+4(x^2+1)+(Dx+E)x^3.
$$
Expanding the right hand side of the above and putting it in standard form:
$$
3x^2 +4=(A+D)x^4+(E+B)x^3+(A+4)x^2+Bx+4
$$
So, equating coefficients:
$$\eqalign{
A&=-D\cr
E&=-B\cr
A&=-1\cr
B&=0;\cr
}
$$
whence $A=-1$, $D=1$, $E=B=0$, and (from before) $C=4$.

So,
$$
{3x^2+4\over x^3(x^2+1)}= {-1\over x}+ {4\over x^3}+{ x \over x^2+1}.
$$

Comment: Ok I promise I will not ask any more question till I get some sleep. Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 3):

To answer the question as asked, it appears given the factor of $1+x^2$ in the denominator, if you want to avoid partial fractions, the substituion

$x=\tan u,dx=\sec^2udu$

looks like it would simplify the denominator.

$\int\dfrac{3x^2+4}{x^5+x^3}dx=\int\dfrac{3\tan^2u+4}{\tan^3u(\tan^2u+1)}\sec^2udu=$

$\int\dfrac{3\tan^2u+4}{\tan^3u\sec^2u}\sec^2udu=$

$\int\dfrac{3\tan^2u+4}{\tan^3u}du=$

$\int3\cot u+4\cot^3udu=\int3\cot u+4\cot u(\csc^2u-1)du=$

$\int-\cot u+4\cot u\csc^2udu=$

$-\ln|\sin u|-2\cot^2u+C$

That first resubstitution is going to be ugly.

$1+\frac1{x^2}=\csc^2u,\dfrac1{1+\frac1{x^2}}=\frac{x^2}{x^2+1}=\sin^2u$

So it looks like we have our result as $-\ln\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{x^2+1}}-\frac2{x^2}+C$

Comment: Nice. A typo: in the fifth equation, you should have $\cot^2 u=\csc^2 u-1$.

Comment: Oops.  I'll have to fix that.

Comment: @David Does it look all right now?  I mean, I could possibly rewrite the ln term, but are there any other errors I missed?

Comment: It looks correct to me now. But, I have been known to make errors myself :)